# PHP CodeIgniter application not opening any page except default controller

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, openshift

My website was hosted on domain seeingtheworld.org and my `htaccess` was as follows:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 1024M
php_value post_max_size 1024M
php_value max_execution_time 2700
php_value max_input_time 2700

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /seeingtheworld
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

This is the link working fine. http://seeing-the-world.org/

Now I have hosted this site on openshift

http://stw-ciapps.rhcloud.com/

It is only opening the home page and no other page. As I have specified home as default controller and do not know what I should change in `htaccess` for this openshift. 
**If I have htaccess then why default root**

Comment: First of all...check if you have the `mod-rewrite` module activated in your new hosting.

Comment: The .htaccess file has been pre-configured to remove trailing slashes and index.php from URLs (based on typical CodeIgniter best-practices).

Comment: Is it opening by passing index.php in url??

Comment: @prashantthakre no, not at all                                                        https://stw-ciapps.rhcloud.com/index.php/home/medicalglossary,             its going back to homepage

Comment: If you don't have that module activated on your hosting the .htaccess is not gonna work

Comment: @RobertRozas, .htaccess module is activated

Answer (score 0):

check with this code to your htaccess.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</Ifmodule>
```

if its still not workings,try with changing "uri_protocol" in config file.

Comment: code not working, what to change in uri_protocol in config file

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my problem was somewhat unrelated. I had to rename my default controller php file to lowercase and the controller class name to lowercase and everything started to work. When CI looks for the default controller file, it searches in lowercase for the file; if I name my controller file "Home.php" instead of "home.php," CI misses it on Linux (since Linux file systems are case sensitive).