# Activate mod_rewrite on openshift

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, openshift, codeigniter-routing

I have PHP codeigniter application that is working fine on shared hosting.

Now I hosted this application on openshift. But .htaccess is not working on openshift. Hence cannot view my site. How can I enable mod_rewrite on openshift to run my .htaccess?

Comment: Mod rewrite is already enabled for applications.  What error are you getting? Have you tried sshing into your application and making sure that your .htaccess file got added to the repo and deployed with your application code?

Comment: Hi, thank you for reply, I have done all please view this question by me  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30240994/php-codeigniter-application-not-opening-any-page-except-default-controller

Answer (score 0):

Do you have acces via SSH?

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
apache2ctl restart
```

Inside your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Check first if apache call your .htaccess, else put AllowOverride All in your virtual host directory root config

Comment: User does not have access to do that on OpenShift.

Comment: You can start with phpinfo() an show if the mod rewrite is active.

Answer (score 0):

compare your .htaccess file with this one.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```